# 2 sheeted covering space over a connected hausdorff space is connected?

Tags: general-topology, riemann-surfaces

This is related to Forster Riemann surfaces Ex 5.7 of Chpt 1.

Suppose $X,Y$ are connected hausdorff spaces. Show that every 2 sheeted covering map $p:Y\to X$ is galois.

Q: Why would be a 2 sheeted covering necessarily be connected here? I can totally have $Y=X\sqcup X$ which is disconnected as $X$ homeo to $X$ itself and thus $Y$ is basically made of two disconnected components. I think my intuitive picture is wrong here.

The reason asking this question is not to look for solution but why I hope $Y$ connected here in general.(Pictorially, I would hope $Y$ looks like $X\sqcup X$. Correct my picture if I am wrong here.) I knew $Y$ being connected used in the proof to show $g\in Deck(Y/X)$ $\{y\in Y\vert g(y)=y\}\sqcup\{y\in Y\vert g(y)\neq y\}$ open disjoint set to see contradiction.

Comment: There is no reason for such a covering to be connected: as you wrote, the disjoint union of two copies of $X$ is not connected. It may be the case that the definition of covering map used in the book includes connectedness of the domain.

Comment: [Wikipedia: Covering space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Formal_definition) explains the connectivity of $Y$ at **Alternative definitions**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connectedness of $Y$ is part of the hypothesis.Otherwise, for a covering map to be Galois, the covering space MUST be connected, by definition.

Comment: This might be a very dumb question. Any particular reason beyond that connectedness implies $K(Y)$ well defined as a field needs connectedness for galois covering. As far as I could see, galois covering should corresponds to functional field galois correspondence in the opposite direction. Is this the whole reason why the book want galois covering to be connected to start with?

Comment: @user45765 What you are describing is the algebraic-geometric point of view. For a topologist, a covering is Galois (regular, normal...) if the fundanental group of the cover is a normal subgroup of the base, and acts nicely on the coset space. If the covering space is a disjoint union of two sheets, the fundamental group is certainly normal, but the action does not come from the group-theoretic action, so this form of "galois correspondence" breaks down.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.